# svn: Can't set permissions on '?\128': No such file or directory

Tags: svn, permissions, collabnet

When doing a

`svn co`

or

`svn up`

from my HP-UX 11.00 to our Windows CollabNet Subversion, with subversion compiled from the subversion-deps package 1.6.20, I get:

`svn: Can't set permissions on '?\128': No such file or directory`

there is no such weird filename in my repo and I can checkout from another host without problems.

This seems to be a random error, if i call

`svn up`

again and again after each error, the whole repo gets checked out in parts.
I get these errors on a Linux svn server as well, so the problem seems to be on client side.

I solved the problem with installing subversion-1.6.1  with deps package.

Comment: Do you have a € symbol somewhere?

Comment: No, not in a file or directory name.